# What are some good books on Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I have been trying to find a good book on Laplace Transform with focus on analytical proofs. Most sources I have read so far are sections from books on differential equations, not so focused on the analysis of the concept. So I wonder what are some of the standard, recommended textbooks on Laplace transform that might be suitable for readers who's familiar with mathematical analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could be Phil Dyke "An Introduction to Laplace Transforms and Fourier Series" Springer
Another one is Peter K. F. Kuhfittig "Introduction to the  Laplace Transform" Springer